# word count textbox javascript/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to implement a word counter in textbox. I am using the links below:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DT5z/9/)
[Second link](https://www.hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/word-count.php)

```
<textarea name="myMessage" onkeyup="wordcount(this.value)"></textarea>
<script type=""text/javascript"">
    var cnt;
    function wordcount(count) {
        var words = count.split(/\s/);
        cnt = words.length;
        var ele = document.getElementById('w_count');
        ele.value = cnt;
    }
    document.write("<input type=text id=w_count size=4 readonly>");
</script>
```

Word counter is working fine. But my scenario is like as below:

1. for word "Most Suitable Match" if user type short form as **"MSM"** then MSM also shall be counted as 3 words.
2. In the same way if there is name of college like "DAV" then it shall also be counted as 3 words.

Please suggest !!

Comment: You'll need a dictionary of permitted acronyms and then loop over each _"word"_ to find acronyms :)

Comment: any examples please?? it would be of great help...

Comment: If you know all the acronyms/shorthands which will be used by the users, you can store them in a javascript object as key, value pairs. (key: acronym, value: word_count) (eg: {"MSM" : 3} )Then inside the wordcount function you can iterate through the 'words' array and check if it is in the javascript object and if so make it count as its value..

Comment: i do not knw all acronyms... that is the sad news :

Comment: you have to find it and add into an object as @tibzon says

Comment: If you assume each letter in an acronym stands for a single word, then the number of words in the acronym is the number of characters it contains.

Comment: yup... i shall do that then... :)  and why dwonvotes... what is wrong in ques

Comment: if you don't know all the acronyms it would be really hard to guess. Because it is not that easy to guess whether a word is an acronym or a real word.

Comment: People just like to downvote on this community @Gags :sss They are just too picky..

Comment: You could do something like `if (words[i].length>1 && words[i].match(/^[A-Z]*$/)) cnt += words[i].length-1)`

Comment: @mplungjan  ... what is this for?? u t mt taking any acronyms

Comment: If you loop over all words, this would add all uppercase words with more than one letter as X number of words where X is the length of the acronym-1 since you already added the word as one word when you counted all words

Comment: but user can also write "msm"

Comment: Then that cannot be considered an acronym that you can detect without using a lookup table. How did you think it could be coded? Any word with more than one consonant ? Then you have member of parliament mop or so to deal with too.

Comment: i though as of using as dictionary... but even then some words can be missed

Comment: That will not work. Too big for client code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have make a simple function:

```
var regex = [/DAV/g, /MAC/g];

function countWords() {
  var count = [];
  regex.forEach(function(reg) {
    var m = text.match(reg);

    if (m) {
      count = count.concat(m);
    }
  });

  // the number of known acronym wrote in the text 
  var acronyms = count.length;

  // how much words generated from an acronym (e.g. DAV === 3 words; AB === 2 words and so on)
  var wordsFromAcronyms = count.join().replace(/,/g,'').length;

  // how many words wrote (this is equal to your code)
  var rawWords = text.match(/\S+/g).length;

  // compute the real number
  return rawWords - acronyms + wordsFromAcronyms;
}
```

It counts the number of the wrote acronym (the list of the known acronyms is stored in `regex` array), then count how much words are generated by the acronyms (`wordsFromAcronym`), and then substract the number of acronyms (`acronyms`) from the total words (`rawWords`) and then add the `wordsFromAcronym`.

Here is a [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rg3ITjhkQLoxrzbLukLt).

Comment: yup... this way i have to find out all acronyms :)

Comment: Yes, but this is the only effective solution cause you can't be sure about user's casing. If a user SHOUT IN UPPERCASE you will reach the maximum number of words quite earlly....

Comment: yup... i liked this approach but firstly let me figure out acronyms

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I am on my mobile so I cannot make an example easily
This will count all words in all uppercase as acronyms

```
<textarea name="myMessage" onkeyup="wordcount(this.value)"></textarea>
<input type=text id=w_count size=4 readonly>
<script type=""text/javascript"">
      function wordcount(message) {
        var words = message.split(/\s/);
        var cnt = words.length;
        for (var i=0;i<cnt;i++) {
          if (words[i].length>1 && words[i].match(/^[A-Z]*$/)) cnt += words[i].length-1)
        }
        var ele = document.getElementById('w_count');
        ele.value = cnt;
    }
</script>
```