# Javascript read time word count textarea

Tags: javascript

This question is based on [Trouble getting real time word count from html textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057103/trouble-getting-real-time-word-count-from-html-textbox).

I am also fairly new to Javascript, and would please like some help in understanding the examples presented on this page. There are multiple lines in the code, in the different examples that have a "text area" tag, yet there is only one text area on the screen. Is this correct?

What I am looking to do is to have multiple text areas on the page, all of which will feed into another page via a form (this part I understand). But, I only want one of the boxes to have the real time word count.

Can someone please assist? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of linking to the code (and much more than just what you have questions about), please post the code here.

Comment: See this answer, maybe it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31629326/6465854